# How to get the right colum type name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, postgis

I need to know the column-type names of a table, and so far i'm using this query :

```
SELECT column_name as name,
        data_type as type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

The problem is that for data types like `geometry` (POSTGIS) it returns `USER-DEFINED` instead of `geometry`.

Is there a way to get the right column-type name?

Comment: Do you need to find the type with an SQL query? If not, doesn't typing `\d MY_TABLE` in `psql` work for you?

Comment: @redneb I would need to do this in a query if posible

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but you could try to use the `pg_typeof` function. It takes a _value_ and returns its type as string. So the downside is that you need to find such a value, which might be a problem e.g. if the table is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this right now, but according to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) for `information_schema.columns`:

> data_type
>
> Data type of the column, if it is a built-in type, or ARRAY if it is
>   some array (in that case, see the view element_types), else
>   USER-DEFINED (in that case, the type is identified in udt_name and
>   associated columns). If the column is based on a domain, this column
>   refers to the type underlying the domain (and the domain is identified
>   in domain_name and associated columns).

So maybe the column `udt_name` contains what you want.

Comment: I'll try as soon as possible. Thank you!!